# Retrieve row of aggregate on primary key with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, aggregate

Ok so I know you can't pull specific fields without an aggregate when you perform a SQL command with a group by, but it seems to me that if you are doing an aggregate on a primary key that is guaranteed to be unique, there should be a way to pull the other rows of that column along with it.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Max(id), 
       foo, 
       bar 
FROM   mytable 
GROUP  BY value1, 
          value2
```

So ID is guaranteed to be unique, so it will have exactly 1 value for foo and bar, is there a way to generate a query like this?

I have tried this, but MyTable in this case has millions of rows, and the run-time for this is unacceptable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(id) 
              FROM   mytable 
              GROUP  BY value1, 
                        value2) 
       AND ...
```

Ideally I would like a solution that works at least as far back as SQL server 2005, but if there are better solutions in the later versions I would like to hear them as well.

Comment: Your current solution will work for versions before SQL Server 2005 as far as I know. And the second query will use `MAX` with a `GROUP BY` as well, so it will be the same as the first solution. So it doesn't seem to be a work around.

Comment: You might want to look into the "partition by" statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have an index defined such as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_GroupBy ON mytable (value1, value2)
```

`IN` can be tend to be slow if you have many rows.  It may help to turn your `IN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    data.*
FROM
    mytable data
        INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id = MAX(id) 
        FROM mytable 
        GROUP BY value1, 
                 value2
    ) ids
        ON data.id = ids.id
```

Unfortunately, Sql Server does not have any features that will do this any better.

Comment: I suppose inner join does make a little more sense, but this is still brutally slow, didn't complete in 5 minutes and I cancelled it.  (and all my group by columns are non-clustered indices)

Comment: @KDiTraglia - are your group by columns in a single non-clustered index or are they indexed separately?  If they are in a single index, are they the only columns in that index?  Check your query plan to see if it is using the index at all.

Comment: Actually they were all indexed separately, I added a index for all of them together and that did help tremendously.  It's still not the fastest thing in the world, but it is at least acceptable.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT foo
       ,bar
       ,MAX(ID) OVER(Partition By Value1, Value2 Order by Value1,Value2)
FROM myTable

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX myIndex ON MyTable(Value1,Value2) INCLUDE(foo,bar)
```

This NCI will cover the whole query, so it will not need to lookup the table at all

Comment: Actually, this will return ALL values of foo and bar, not just the values associated with the max id.